# Circle scale animation works a bit weird

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

I am animating my GMSMarker so that it pulse once in couple seconds.

```
func addWave()
    {
//        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2

        //Scale
        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = 1
        scaleAnimation.toValue = zoom

        //Opacity
        let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        alphaAnimation.toValue = 0.0

        //Corner radius
//        let cornerRadiusAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
//        cornerRadiusAnimation.fromValue = size / 2
//        cornerRadiusAnimation.toValue = (size * zoom)/2

        //Animation Group
        let animations: [CAAnimation] = [scaleAnimation, alphaAnimation]

        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.duration = duration
        animationGroup.animations = animations
        animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        animationGroup.repeatCount = 1
        animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        circleView.layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "group")
    }
```

The result looks like this:

[image] [image]

And if I uncomment `Corner radius` section it looks like this:

[image]

So I need an advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my observations, I think it must be a issue of wrong path of your CAShapeLayer hence the masking of the circle.

I just wrote a radar animation, I hope it might help you.

```
    let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = 0
    scaleAnimation.toValue = 1

    let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
    alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

    let animations = CAAnimationGroup()
    animations.duration = 0.8
    animations.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    animations.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    animations.animations = [scaleAnimation, alphaAnimation]

    circleView.layer.add(animations, forKey: "animations")
```

What I did was, I used two CAShapeLayer (one being the orange marker and other is the rader layer at the back of marker). The animations were applied on the radar layer.

```
    radarLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    radarLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height);
    radarLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: radarLayer.frame).cgPath
    radarLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    radarLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    radarLayer.cornerRadius = radarLayer.frame.size.width/2
    radarLayer.masksToBounds = true
    radarLayer.opacity = 0
    self.layer.addSublayer(radarLayer)

    circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 16, height: 16);
    circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: circleLayer.frame).cgPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    circleLayer.cornerRadius = circleLayer.frame.size.width/2
    circleLayer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

PS. I'm new to Swift, so enlighten me if I'm wrong somewhere :)

Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejx8Q.jpg

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I messed up with layers and basic knowledge, your answer helped me to get It right :)

Answer (score 0):

The following in an excerpt from Google documentation on Markers:

> The view behaves as if **clipsToBounds is set to YES**, regardless of its actual value. You can apply transforms that work outside the bounds, but the object you draw must be within the bounds of the object. All transforms/shifts are monitored and applied. In short: subviews must be contained within the view.

The consequence of that, at least for my case, was exactly the behaviour mentioned in the question: a squared circle animation. The image I wanted to add inside the marker, at the end of the animation, was bigger than the container, so once added to the marker, it was clipped to the bounds of it.

The following is what I did:

```
public var pulseImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    imageView.image = PaletteElements.pulseLocation.value
    imageView.contentMode = .center

    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = 0
    pulseAnimation.toValue = 2.0
    pulseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    fadeOutAnimation.duration = 2.5
    fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = 1.0
    fadeOutAnimation.toValue = 0
    fadeOutAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.duration = 2.5
    animationGroup.animations = [pulseAnimation, fadeOutAnimation]
    animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)
    animationGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    animationGroup.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    animationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    imageView.layer.add(animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")

    return imageView
}()
```

I defined a var inside my helper class so I can retrieve the image whenever I need it. My original image, the pulse image, was 116x116, so I created the imageView as 300x300 with a contentMode = .center, so the small image was in the center and not stretched. I chose 300x300 because my animation scaled up the pulse image until a 2x its initial value (116x2), so I made room for the entire animation to be performed.

Finally I added it to as a Marker to the map:

```
let pulseMarker = GMSMarker(position: userLocation.coordinate)
pulseMarker.iconView = pulseImageView
pulseMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
pulseMarker.map = googleMapView
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Here it is the link to the Google doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker